# ReactJS with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i creating a form with React-selec.
When i do a function and pass parameters he returns me
**Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.tsx(31, 31): An argument for 'selectRef' was not provided.**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    function parseSelectValue(selectRef: { state: { value: any } }) {
      const selectValue = selectRef.state.value
      if (!multiple) {
        return selectValue ? selectValue.id : ''
      }

      return selectValue
        ? selectValue.map((option: { id: any }) => option.id)
        : []
    }
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: ref.current as any,
      path: 'state.value',
      parseValue: parseSelectValue,
      clearValue: (selectRef: { select: { clearValue: () => void } }) => {
        selectRef.select.clearValue()
      }
    })
    parseSelectValue()
  }, [fieldName, registerField, multiple])
```

Comment: Questions are required to be in English on SO. Also, please edit your title to ask a question rather than list tags.

Comment: Please either edit and translate to English, or post to pt.stackoverflow.com (Portuguese-specific Q&A site).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English.

Answer (score 0):

The function parseSelectValue expects a selectRef; Its a non-optional parameter.

```
    function parseSelectValue(selectRef?: { state: { value: any } }) {
        const selectValue = selectRef ? selectRef.state.value : undefined;
```

Paste this should fix the problem.